# Advice on sql server index performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have "UserLog" table with 15 millions rows.

On this table I have a cluster index on ***User_ID*** field which is of type bigint identity, and a non clustered index on ***User_uid*** field which is of type varchar(35) (a fake uniqueidentifier).

On my application we can have 2 categories of users connection. 1 of them concerns only 0.007% of rows (about 1150 raws over 15 millions) and the 2nd concerns the remaining rows (99%).

The objective is to improve performance of the 0.007% users connection.

That's why I create a 'split' field "***Userlog_ID***" with type bit with default value of 0. So for each user connection we insert a new row in Userlog (with 0 as a value for User_log).

This field (User_Log) will then be update and it will take either 0 (for more then 99% of rows) or 1 (for 0.007% of rows) depending on the user category.

I create then a non clustered index on this field (User_log).

the select statment I want to optimize is:

```
SELECT      User_UID, User_LastAuthentificationDate, 
Language_ID,User_SecurityString
FROM        dbo.UserLog
WHERE        User_Active = 1                                   
AND User_UID = '00F5AA38-C288-48C6-8ED1922601819486'
```

So the idea is now to add a filter on User_Log field to optimise the performance (precisely the index seek operator), only when the user belongs to the category 1 (0.007%):

```
SELECT      User_UID, User_LastAuthentificationDate, Language_ID,User_SecurityString
FROM        dbo.UserLog
WHERE        User_Active = 1                                  
AND User_UID = '00F5AA38-C288-48C6-8ED1922601819486' 
and User_Log = 1
```

In my mind, I have the idea that since we add this filter the index seek will perform better because we have now a smaller result set.

Unfortunately, when I compare the 2 queries with the estimated execution plan I obtain 50% for each query. For both queries the optimiser use an index seek on user_uid non clustered index and then a key lookup on the cluster index (User_id).

So In conclusion by adding the split field and a non clustered index (either normal or filtered) on it, I don't improve the performance.

Can anyone have an explanation why. Maybe my reasoning and my interpretation are totaly wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Two ideas: 1) You may use WHERE in non-clustered indexes to build index for category 1 rows only; 2) You may use partitioning in MSSQL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) to separate rows of different categories into different FILEGROUPS - but it needs Enterprise version of MSSQL - read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx

Comment: Have you looked at filtered indexes? You can add a WHERE clause on the CREATE INDEX and it will only index the User_Log = 1 in the b-tree.

Comment: Yes. Filtered indexes were the first thing to my mind.

Comment: As I already said I also tried the filtered index but I get also the same results (50%). In my opinion I will benefit from this index only if I use partitionning

Comment: Is the User_Active-field in your `WHERE`-statement indexed?

Comment: No it is not indexed. I think that since I have the condition on User_UID and since this field is indexed, even if I create the split field and I indexed it with a filtered index, the optimizer still use an index seek on the User_UID index because the condition on User_uid field is with the "=" operator. However if the condition was: and user_uid <> 'xxxx', the optimizer will benefit from the filtered index. Right??

Comment: When you added your filtered index, did you check to see if it was used in the query plan? I suggest you continue your investigations down that path.

Comment: Hello Nick. That is what surprising me!! Even after adding the filtered index on User_Log, the optimiser still use an index seek on the non clustered index (User_UID). Is it true that  once we have the following condition: "and user_uid ='xxxxxxx' the optimiser choose always an index seek on User_uid non clustered index regardless what are the present indexes on the table?? and that just in case we don't have an equal condition on User_uid we will benefit from the filtered index?? Remark: we don't use yet partitionning